# Danish characters not supported on UTF-8 encoded application

Tags: character-encoding, dojo, unsupportedoperation

I am working on a application based on java, javascript(dojo). When the user enters danish characters, they are converted into question marks. I have checked that throughout the application only UTF-8 encoding is used. Also I have tried different encoding schemes but to no-effect.
One solution I found suggested to save the data in a notepad file and then use the same.....that also yields nothing.
Can anybody suggest what might be causing this issue?
Appreciate your help!
thank you.

Comment: If they appear as “�”, as I suspect, the probable reason is that the character data is not UTF-8 encoded after all but Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 or some similar data being misinterpreted as UTF-8. Without information about the actual context (method of input, program code used to handle it, processing of data, etc.) it is hardly possible to say more.

Comment: Does your system have fonts of Danish characters?

Comment: are you able to type in danish characters in any of your word processors that suppor it? can you write a simple webpage that contains danish characters?